# How can i make sure a field is greater than an other field on sql update

Tags: mysql, sql

i am developing an application to capture the work hours of employees.  The start value of a work day gets rounded up and the end value gets rounded down to the next full five minutes. what happens if an employee clicks on end right after he started is, that the end is now before.

what i tried before:

```
UPDATE `work_hours`
SET
END = (
    CASE
    END
    WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 300)
    ) < START THEN
        START
    ELSE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 300)
        )
    END
)
WHERE
    `id` = 'xyz'
```

But it always inserts the rounded down time...
I dont want to use a trigger. Is there a way to do this

Comment: This query will choke right here: `CASE end WHEN`

Comment: or use trigger [http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php]

Comment: possibly your application should catch this situation in the business logica as a validation error - don't allow users to enter blocks of time less than 10 minutes long (unless that's a valid, realistic amount of work for a day). Or you could use a trigger to examine the table afterwards and correct the data, but IMO this is less desirable.

Comment: A database is just a data storage facility. It's not meant for business logic. And your business logic here needs to be reworked, because it allows negative working times. If you really really need to do this in mysql (which I would not advise) than you can use a stored procedure to calculate the work hours and update/insert them.

Comment: @Seb, I can't find the proper way to start explaining why I think you are completely wrong. Most DBMSs provide a programming language just for that, implementing business logic. An experienced designer will know where to set the boundaries, but will not automatically disqualify the DB as a possible location for (at least part of) the business logic.

Comment: As for the OP question, you can place your `UPDATE` within an `IF`, or prepare the values for the update **before** the update. That is what I would do and leave the update simple.

Comment: @Fdavidov - "completely wrong" is hard wording. I know that you can do some logic in DBMSs, more specific Mysql. That's why I mentioned stored procedures. But first that business logic has a flaw, no matter where you implement it - and second I guess there is a lot more business logic involved with working time tracking than just the updates. I would not advise to do this in any DMBSs programming language.

Comment: @Seb I didn't mean to be rude but only underline the fact that I completely (180 degrees!) disagree with you. Additionally, MySQL has weak programming capabilities when you compare it against, for instance, SQL-Server or Oracle's PL/SQL (incredibly rich). Just as an additional example, most modern DBMSs support JSON manipulations, and it would be fare to assume that these capabilities were not added just for the fun of having them.

Comment: @FDavidov Understood. But it's Mysql here. And no matter what language - the business logic needs reworking here. Hope we can settle on this. In the end they can steal 9 minutes from me every day, if I time it wrong.

Comment: Agreed. We remain friends of course :-).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a query like this:

```
UPDATE `work_hours` 
SET end = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 300)), 
end = IF(end < start, `start`, `end` ) 
WHERE `id` = 'xyz';
```